# Converting a .xlsx date into a normal date

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I've been using xlrd3 to manage a .xlsx spreadsheet through python. When I'm given the value of the cell the date should be in, it gives me 44295, which should be 09/04/2021.

I understand that this is because of the format excel stores dates as, so I've been using the `xldate_as_datetime` function in this way:

```
 lastsold = itemworksheet.cell_value(i,32)
 lastsold_date = xlrd3.xldate_as_datetime(lastsold,0)
 lastsold_object = lastsold_date.date()
 lastsold_string = lastsold_object.isoformat()
```

(i is an interable from  a 'for' loop)

When the code is `(lastsold,0)` I get the error

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

And when the code is `(lastsold,1)` I get the error.

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

What can I do so I can get the date in the format 09/04/2021 in python?

Comment: it is working well, I think.

Comment: In `itemworksheet.cell_value(i,32)`, is `i` int or str?

Comment: 'i' is the iterable from a 'for' loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested with below code and it works well. Please check it.

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xlsx")
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

val = first_sheet.cell_value(0, 1)
lastsold_date = xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(val, 1)
obj = lastsold_date.date()

print(obj.isoformat())
```

Comment: When I tried your code out individually, it worked. However, when I tried to implement this onto my excel file in my normal code, it produces the same error.

Comment: Then, please open excel file and select column or row that you want to convert into date and right click / Format Cells. And go to Number tab and then select `Number` tag in `Category` list. After that, please run your code, again. Please let me know the result.

Comment: it is working well, but as it iterates through the dates it encounters an error when there is a blank cell.